# How to add tag to UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I have implemented a custom animation to my navigation controller using `MyNavigationControllerAnimations` ,and I need to change the animation according to user activity.

So the `MyNavigationControllerAnimations` will run the suitable animation according to the animation tag:

```
class MyNavigationControllerAnimations: NSObject ,UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning{
    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

       if(transitionContext.tag == '1')
             runAnimate1();
        if(transitionContext.tag == '2')
             runAnimate2();
        if(transitionContext.tag == '3')
             runAnimate3();

        }
}
```

and here the navigation delegate:

```
class UINavigationControllDelegateCustomAnimation: NSObject,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerForOperation operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, fromViewController fromVC: UIViewController, toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return MyNavigationControllerAnimations();
    }

}
```

And before pushing new `viewController` to the navigation I will set the tag, which will identify the animation type:

```
self.navigationController!.animationTag = '1';
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated:true);
```

How could I implement animationTag? Thanks!

Comment: yes that's right , thanks, if you wish you could add it as an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass UINavigationController and add an animationTag property.